# Matching algorithm for objects in Java + Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, algorithm, hibernate

Im writing an app with Spring MVC and Hibernate, Im studing it. I have object Person with 12 variables. The task is to find existing object Person from database that matches the best to comparable's. For example inputPerson_1 match databasePerson_423 for 9 variables witch is 75% match.

I have the following idea but it's looks very overloading for database and obviously a weak solution:

1) create 12 consecutive queries to MySQL to collect all the possible match objects and save to HashSet where first param will be Person ID

```
query = session.createQuery("from Person where lower(firstName) like :inputFirstName) 
query = session.createQuery("from Person where lower(lastName) like :inputLastName) 
...
```

2) create int max and compare object's vars from HashSet one-by-one. Return object with the highest match.

**What is the best option to do it? Maybe there are some ready-to-use solutions?**

Answer (score 0):

I would only execute one database query which would search if any of the attribute is a match.

Then I would write a function which calculates for each Person how many attributes matches and return a value of best match.

Then you can order the list for your best match value.

Of course there are endless ways to solve the problem and each has it's own Pro and Cons.

So, here are the pro and cons for my suggested solution:

Pro's:

- You have less interaction with the database. => It should be a faster solution then the one in the answer.
- You be very flexible about the calculation of the best match. It's one function where you could check and calculate pretty everything you want.

Con's:

- You have two sections in different places which have to be in sync. The db query which search for all criterias and the calculation function which checks the same attributes. => hidden contract and coupling
- If the search for the criteria will return massive set of entries this solution is not a good fit. Then you have to calculate the factor inside the db in some way and you need to use indexes which works with order and limit, so you don't return all rows and have a effort class of O(log(n)).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone will find this answer useful for its own proposes...
I decide to follow the easiest way for now. 
**For finding the similar objects :**

```
public List<Person> searchSimilarPeople(Person person) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Query query = null;
    query = session.createQuery("from Person where lower(firstName) like :s_name or lower(lastName) like :f_name " +
            "or lower(email) like :email or lower(address1) like :address1 or lower(address2) like :address2 " +
            "or lower(city) like :city or lower(region_state) like :state or lower(zip) like :zip " +
            "or lower(country) like :country", Person.class);
    query.setParameter("s_name", "%" + person.getFirstName() + "%");
    query.setParameter("f_name", "%" + person.getLastName() + "%");
    query.setParameter("address1", "%" + person.getAddress1() + "%");
    query.setParameter("address2", "%" + person.getAddress2() + "%");
    query.setParameter("city", "%" + person.getCity() + "%");
    query.setParameter("state", "%" + person.getRegion_state() + "%");
    query.setParameter("zip", "%" + person.getZip() + "%");
    query.setParameter("country", "%" + person.getCountry() + "%");
    query.setParameter("email", "%" + person.getEmail() + "%");
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

I've tried to dive into Hibernate Search process with Lucene but it looks not the best option for a beginner in Hibernate I think. But I will be appreciated if someone will provide the brief explanation of same process using Lucene :)

**For Object comparing :**
Almost all vars in the comparing objects are String, so I decide to use Jaro-Winkler distance to get the string match coefficient and after that to multiply it to 0.11 (I have 9 variables to compare so max possible match result is 0.99)

```
 @Override
public Double getMatch(Person inputPerson, Person dbPerson) {
    double intermResult = 0;
    double finalResult = 0;
    // FirstName
    intermResult = StringUtils.getJaroWinklerDistance(inputPerson.getFirstName().toLowerCase(), dbPerson.getFirstName().toLowerCase());
    finalResult += (intermResult * rateCoefficient);
    // LAST NAME
    intermResult = StringUtils.getJaroWinklerDistance(inputPerson.getLastName().toLowerCase(), dbPerson.getLastName().toLowerCase());
    finalResult += (intermResult * rateCoefficient);
    // Email
    intermResult = StringUtils.getJaroWinklerDistance(inputPerson.getEmail().toLowerCase(), dbPerson.getEmail().toLowerCase());
    finalResult += (intermResult * rateCoefficient);
    // ADDRESS 1
    intermResult = StringUtils.getJaroWinklerDistance(inputPerson.getAddress1().toLowerCase(), dbPerson.getAddress1().toLowerCase());
    finalResult += (intermResult * rateCoefficient);
    // ADDRESS 2
    if (inputPerson.getAddress2() != null && dbPerson.getAddress2() != null) {
        intermResult = StringUtils.getJaroWinklerDistance(inputPerson.getAddress2().toLowerCase(), dbPerson.getAddress2().toLowerCase());
        finalResult += (intermResult * rateCoefficient);
    }
    // CITY
    intermResult = StringUtils.getJaroWinklerDistance(inputPerson.getCity().toLowerCase(), dbPerson.getCity().toLowerCase());
    finalResult += (intermResult * rateCoefficient);
    // STATE
    if (inputPerson.getRegion_state() != null && dbPerson.getRegion_state() != null) {
        intermResult = StringUtils.getJaroWinklerDistance(inputPerson.getRegion_state().toLowerCase(), dbPerson.getRegion_state().toLowerCase());
        finalResult += (intermResult * rateCoefficient);
    }
    // ZIP
    intermResult = StringUtils.getJaroWinklerDistance(inputPerson.getZip().toLowerCase(), dbPerson.getZip().toLowerCase());
    finalResult += (intermResult * rateCoefficient);
    // COUNTRY
    intermResult = StringUtils.getJaroWinklerDistance(inputPerson.getCountry().toLowerCase(), dbPerson.getCountry().toLowerCase());
    finalResult += (intermResult * rateCoefficient);

    finalResult = Precision.round(finalResult, 3);
    System.out.println("Final Result. ID : " + dbPerson.getId() + " " + finalResult);
    return finalResult;
}
```